# Hot Chocolate GraphQL method versioning

Tags: graphql, hotchocolate

How i can implement the Hot Chocolate GraphQL method versioning similar like to REST, i.e. /graphql/v1 or using request header. i don't want to use Deprecating fields because there is no any change in input or out param but i have change in method implementation(business wise).

Answer (score 1):

GraphQL has no concept of versioning. What you would tend to do is still deprecate and introduce a new method under a new name.

Hot Chocolate can expose multiple schemas though, so you can host two separate schemas on the same server.

`services.AddGraphQLServer("a")`
`services.AddGraphQLServer("b")`

in the `MapGraphQL` method, you would need to map a specific schema to a specific route.

`app.MapGraphQL("/graphql/a", schemaName: "a")`

Having multiple versions of the schema will not scale very well and the more you introduce of these the harder it will get.

Comment: Thanks Michael, can we also use the request header instead of schema app.MapGraphQL("/graphql/a", schemaName: "a") –

Comment: We have not added this capability... but in theory, that would also work. We can have a look on adding this for version 13